# jQuery saving data on every refresh page

Tags: jquery

I'm new on js, saw a code and would like to save it changed value every refresh page. Example: I have value 100 and changes to 150 after 5 seconds, when page refresh value is stored as 150 not 100. I don't know how to go on with it, couldn't get it done with local storage. Here is my code:

```
 HTML:

 <h2 id="cont"></h2>

 JS:

 <script type="text/javascript">
  let genRnd = function() {
      var min=0; 
      var max=9;  
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
  };

  setInterval(
      function() { 
          document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML = genRnd();
      }, 
      500
  );

</script>
```

Comment: Use `localStorage` to save values.

Comment: @Barmer... I don't know so much on localStorage....can you implement localStorage using my code?

Comment: I'm not going to do it for you. Google it and learn.

Comment: @Barmar... I'm working on a project and for me to get it in correctly, sure I will learn more on localStorage, I'm new to it. Kindly help me with the code, it will be of helpful and understandable for me when learning localStorage. Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: It would have taken you less time to look up a tutorial on this than it took to write the question, but I gave it to you anyway.

Comment: @Barmar...I'm new to js, so much to learn. Thanks code worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the random number in `localStorage`. When the page loads, get the previous value from there.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let random = localStorage.getItem("random");
  if (random) {
    document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML = random;
  }
});

let genRnd = function() {
  var min = 0;
  var max = 9;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min;
};

setInterval(
  function() {
    let random = genRnd();
    document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML = random;
    localStorage.setItem("random", random);
  },
  500
);
```

Comment: We have many, many duplicates on how to use localstorage too; there was no need to add yet another...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Probably, but none of them would have shown how to refactor to assign the random number to a variable before saving. I'll bet he would have written `localStorage.setItem("random", getRnd());`

Comment: ... which would have been a better, more narrowly focused question. As it is, we have yet another question about how to persist data across page refreshes. The goal of Stack Overflow is not to just help the individual asking the question, but everyone else who finds the question later.

Comment: Sure, but he doesn't know that he needs to ask that. It's hard to ask the right question when you don't know what you don't know.

Comment: And heaven forfend you take some time to educate the user. Wouldn't want to take time away from your rep-earning...

Comment: Look, I decided to take pity on him. So sue me.